# AttributeError: 'DataSourceNoCloud' object has no attribute 'vendordata2_raw'

Tags: unattended-upgrades

Last unnattended upgrade has returned error with service 'cloud-init'. I copy the error from "journalctl -u cloud-init":

br 16 06:39:29 alestis cloud-init[1187]: AttributeError: 'DataSourceNoCloud' object has no attribute 'vendordata2_raw'
abr 16 06:39:29 alestis cloud-init[1187]: ------------------------------------------------------------
abr 16 06:39:29 alestis systemd[1]: cloud-init.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
abr 16 06:39:29 alestis systemd[1]: cloud-init.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 16 06:39:29 alestis systemd[1]: Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).

• Last runing version = Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
• Failed one = Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~18.04.1

Please, Is safe downgrading only the cloud-init package to last runninng version?, It is better to wait until bug is fixed?

Comment: I now have the same issue. Found this bug report on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1922739

Answer (score 0):

As per bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1922739 this is now fixed.

As per bug discussion, a manual workaround is to run `sudo cloud-init clean` and then restart the cloud-init.service service (or reboot).

Comment: Hello Jeremy,

Thank you so much for the replay. Regrettably I tried this workaround without success.

Anyway, service is disabled and system is OK. No problem.

Comment: As per the launchpad link, the bug itself has been fixed and the updated package has been published to the various repositories. You should not need to make any changes other than updating the cloud-init package.